# Using MySQL triggers

Tags: mysql

I have `items` table and `item_records` table. I want it such that, whenever I do **anything** to `items`, be it adding item, deleting it (I have both of these done via stored procedures), or changing its `ItemAmount`, the state of that item gets logged as row in `item_records`.

Is it possible to write trigger and access the row that got inserted, deleted, or updated? So far, I have seen no MySQL triggers that work like that. (Mind you, I am thinking of event-based actions in terms of Java/JavaScript, where event is passed as object.)

Comment: Looks to me like that's exactly what MySQL triggers can do: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html You access the newly updated/inserted/deleted row using the `NEW` keyword, and can perform whatever insertions or updates into `item_records` you want.

Comment: in mysql AfterUpdate trigger you can "new" and "old" variables to get the old and new rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, I created two tables on my MySQL server as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE items (
   item_id int not null auto_increment primary key,
   item_amount double,
   description varchar(50)
);

CREATE TABLE item_records (
   record_id int not null auto_increment primary key,
   item_id int not null,
   status varchar(100)
);
```

and I then created the following three triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_item AFTER INSERT ON items
  FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO item_records(item_id, status) 
    VALUES (NEW.item_id, "Inserted")
;

CREATE TRIGGER del_item AFTER DELETE ON items
  FOR EACH ROW
     INSERT INTO item_records(item_id, status) 
     VALUES (OLD.item_id, "Deleted")
;

CREATE TRIGGER upd_item AFTER UPDATE ON items
  FOR EACH ROW
     INSERT INTO item_records(item_id, status) 
      VALUES (OLD.item_id, CONCAT("Updated Amt ", OLD.item_amount, " to ", NEW.item_amount))
;
```

After inserting 5 items, then updating one and deleting one, like so:

```
INSERT INTO items (item_amount, description) VALUES (25.50, "Gibit");
INSERT INTO items (item_amount, description) VALUES (10, "Gibit2");
INSERT INTO items (item_amount, description) VALUES (18.25, "Gibit3");
INSERT INTO items (item_amount, description) VALUES (12, "Gibit4");
INSERT INTO items (item_amount, description) VALUES (1.99, "Gibit5");

UPDATE items SET item_amount = 1999.99 WHERE item_id = 4;
DELETE FROM items WHERE item_id = 3;
```

my tables look like this:

[image: items table]

`items`

[image: item_records table]

`item_records`

(the disparity with `item_id` not starting at 1 is because I screwed up a first attempt at inserting, which "used up" the auto-increment value of 1, and I didn't bother resetting it first)